# Sweet alert html option

Tags: javascript, html, css, sweetalert

I'm trying to make an sweet alert with the html option:

```
swal({  
   title: "HTML <small>Title</small>!",  
   text: "A custom <span style="color:#F8BB86">html<span> message.",   
   html: true 
});
```

But instead of that text put a button, I have tried this one:

```
var boton = "button";
swal({   
    title: "HTML <small>Title</small>!",  
    text: "<input type=" + boton + ">",  
    html: true 
});
```

but it doesn't work!
(I want to make something like a menu with options(the buttons))
Does anybody know how to do something like that?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the fiddle demo?

Comment: do u want text instead of button in http://jsfiddle.net/BDhara/xe096w10/160/

Comment: Is sweetalert a plugin?

Comment: mmm...I want soemthing more like a menu with
(button1) Option1
(button2) Option2
(button3) Option3
The thing is that in the first code the second quotation marks work fine (in the style) 
But when i try my code it shows a "html"file but not the button. I mean if you put a <p> appears,an <br> and other stuffs but the input doesn't work

a piece of code that may help:
 if(keyMap & 4){
here the sweet alert
}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `button` tag instead of `input`.

Like this:

```js
var boton = "button";
swal({   
    title: "HTML <small>Title</small>!",  
    text: '<button type="' + boton + '">Button</button>',
    html: true 
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Its done! (i think :/ i'm new and i dont know where to click)

Comment: Thanks! it's done.. Welcome to StackOverflow ;) By the way, you can [upvote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow) too (if you didn't do it already)..

Comment: Thats nice, mm..can you answer another question please? 
what if I want to put an onclick  inside? that calls a function for example checkName();

Comment: Do you mean that you want to show 2 buttons: 1 is OK and 1 is `checkName`?

Comment: I mean one is for checkName() another one to antotherThing() then, doSomething() in other button.
edit: the thing is that if i put-> if(keyMap & 4){ show the swal }<- the code just do the onClick function every time I press the button

Comment: You can't do this with the plugin so I updated the plugin. Download the script from by [github](https://github.com/moshfeu/sweetalert) and tell me if it works.

Comment: i don't know why but in the example(index.html) works but in my code no hahaha .
Just copy and paste. i have check the link and script line (on the top) just every thing where is soppose to be.

Comment: Any erros in the `console`?

Comment: I chaned only the `dev` script, not the minify. The example use it too. I'm tin to find out how to "compile" it. The plugin use `gump`. For now, take the `dev` version script.

Comment: I use html attribute and write my  html code inside it and it works for me.
for example: 
swal({
html:"<a href='#'> Link</a>})

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the button is not shown in the alert is because the css rules regarding `inputs` are by default set to hide them.

You can override the default css behavior of sweetalets by using:

```
.sweet-alert input {
  display: initial !important;
}
```

What I would suggest is give a class to your input, and add explicit rules in your CSS so it doesn't interfere with any other `input` tags used by the plugin.